# How can I use grep or awk to count violations of ScanJS rules to assist with security reviews in a text file report?

Tags: javascript, owasp

I am trying to create a script using grep and/or awk that answers the questions listed below (refer to the figures for visual reference)

1. How many lines within a giant text file, titled “results.txt” contain the text “scanjs-rules/”?
2. How many of those lines in “results.txt” match up with the first entry in Figure 2?
3. How many of those lines match up with the second entry in Figure 2? (continue to the end of those list of 108 rules)
4. How can we create the example report listed in Figure 3?

Motivations:
The reports generated by ESLint address each individual file and  the potential violations for each file - but from what I understand I can't generate any statistics to help someone perform a secure code review on this.

Note: I used the ESLint config file for ScanJS to generate these text file reports but I want to make them easier to read.

[image: Figures 1-3]

**Edit**:

I formatted the rules so each of them looks like this:
`accidental_assignment`

instead of:
`"scanjs-rules/accidental_assignment": 1`

Then I ran this command:

`while read l; do grep -i "${l//\"/}" results.txt; done < rules.txt`

The nice part about this: it prints out each rule violation in alphabetical order, and identifers to help you look through the results.txt file.

Resulting image: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmPPb.jpg)

Desired improvements: I still want it to print out the actual rule and then the count - as shown in Figure 3. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you provide results.txt and I'll take a crack at it

Comment: The results: http://pastebin.com/ydx8MNLt

Comment: The rules: http://pastebin.com/Z1Vz5iCw

Comment: Questions on how to write a script are better asked on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to count lines containing **searched** string with this command :

```
cat results.txt | grep <searched> | wc -l
```

All together

```
for f in `sed -e 's/"\(.*\/\)\(.*\)\(".*\)/\1\2/' pattern.txt`;
  do printf $f' - '; cat result.txt | grep $f | wc -l;
done
```

will print result like

```
scanjs-rules/accidental_assignment - 2
scanjs-rules/assign_to_hostname - 2
scanjs-rules/assign_to_href - 4
```

Where

```
$ cat pattern.txt
"scanjs-rules/accidental_assignment":1,
"scanjs-rules/assign_to_hostname":1,
"scanjs-rules/assign_to_href":1,
```

and result file sample:

```
$cat result.txt
This is dummy line
312:9 warrning from scanjs-rules/accidental_assignment
Another dummy line
Another dummy line
Another dummy line
312:9 warrning from scanjs-rules/assign_to_hostname
312:9 warrning from scanjs-rules/accidental_assignment
Another dummy line
312:9 warrning from scanjs-rules/assign_to_href
Another dummy line
312:9 warrning from unsafe scanjs-rules/assign_to_hostname
312:9 warrning from scanjs-rules/assign_to_href
312:9 warrning from scanjs-rules/assign_to_href
312:9 warrning from scanjs-rules/assign_to_href
```

Comment: Like I said in a comment above... doing that doesn't list out the count for every rule listed within rules.txt. It lists the total amount of occurrences. I still want it to print out the actual rule (there are 108 of them in rules.txt) and then the count - as shown in Figure 3.

Comment: Updated - let me know if it helped

Comment: Looks great but will check when I get home tonight. Thank you.

Comment: Great to hear. Can you please accept the answer (big number on left)?

Comment: Done. To anyone else who is curious, I used the OWASP juice shop application which is a vulnerable JavaScript application. vulnerable-app (search on github) is also good

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
cat results.txt | grep scanjs-rules | wc
```

- cat will display the contents of results.txt
- grep will select those
  lines that contain "scanjs-rules"
- wc will do a word count the first number is the number of lines which is your answer

Comment: let me know if you need help with the rest of the queries, but a good understanding of this technique should work for all parts of the question

Comment: Thanks, Mike! I edited my question so I was able to show my partially working commands. Would love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: Multiple commands and pipes are unnecessary; it can be done in a single grep with `grep -c scanjs-rules results.txt`.

Comment: korockinout13 - yes, but it doesn't list out the count for every rule listed within rules.txt. See my recent edit